# Google Maps Api :set the center of map to different coordinates after rendering

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, web

I want to change the center of google map after some time interval so that it can focus on certain areas of the whole continent having markers showing restaurants branches. I have successfully rendered the map with markers. What i am having problem is changing the center looping through a list of latitude and longitude. I am trying to do something like this.

```
var lat[];
        var lang[];

            function moveToLocation(){
                var center = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
                map.panTo(center);
            }

             setInterval(moveToLocation, 3000);
```

Comment: What do you consider "centre"? Literally just the centre of the map?

Comment: What does your list of latitudes and longitudes look like?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue you are encountering.  Why is this not a duplicate of [How to change center of map after a fixed time interval in google maps api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33281370/how-to-change-center-of-map-after-a-fixed-time-interval-in-google-maps-api)?

Comment: @geocodezip i tried doing that :using a **Complete**  **Tested** and **Readable** example but u voted it down. so i need to make another question. Anyways there is a list of coordinates (lat, lang) and i want to loop it  over and setting map center to the next  coordinates  after a set time interval.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google maps dynamically zooming in different locations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22528391/google-maps-dynamically-zooming-in-different-locations)

Comment: @AdamJeffers Not literrally center of the map coz that would be one but i want to pan it to different coordinates by using either map.setcenter(lat,lang) or map.panTo(lat,lang). The problem is changing the lat/lang after a set time interval.

Comment: @geocodezip yeah its kinda same. Thanks for the refer. The answer is not accepted but i could surely use the logic.

Comment: Just because the answer isn't accepted doesn't mean it doesn't work (or can't be made to work) [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/Ls7j6dL8/1/)

Comment: @geocodezip It worked fine. If u put it in a separate answer so that i could accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this related question: [Google maps dynamically zooming in different locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22528391/google-maps-dynamically-zooming-in-different-locations)

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/Ls7j6dL8/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

  var places = [
    [52, -1],
    [52, -2],
    [53, -3],
    [53, -5],
    [54, -4],
    [54, -6]
  ];

  var index = 0;
  zoomInterval = setInterval(function() {
    var lat = places[index][0];
    var lng = places[index][1];
    index = (index + 1) % places.length;
    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));

  }, 5000);


}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work, not tested though...

```
function moveToLocation(){
    map.panTo(map.getCenter());
}

setInterval(moveToLocation, 3000);
```